# Energy estimate for $u_{tt} - u_{xx} = 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

My PDE textbook says that if $u$ is a solution to 
\begin{align*}
    u_{tt} - u_{xx} = 0\\
    u_x(t,0) = u_x(t,l) = 0\\
    u(0,x) = f(x)\\
    u_t(0,x) = g(x)\\
\end{align*}
Then the energy estimate is
\begin{align*}
    \int_0^l u_t^2(t,x)dx + \int_0^l u_x^2(t,x)dx = \int_0^l f^2(x)dx + \int_0^l g_x^2(x)dx
\end{align*}
I am trying to really understand why this is the case and I am wondering if anyone is able to formally prove this?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to multiply your PDE with $u_t$ and integrate over both time and space:
$$\int_0^t\int_0^l(u_{tt}u_t-u_{xx}u_t)dxdt=0$$
Now use the facts that
$$u_{tt}u_t=\frac12(u_t^2)_t$$
and apply partial integration ovjer the $x$ variable (use the boundary conditions to deal with the boudnary terms appearing from the partial integration) on the second to get a term of the form 
$$u_xu_{xt}=\frac12(u_x^2)_t,$$
now integrate over time and use the initial condition.

If this is not explicit enough, I can add additional explanations, but you should be good.

EDIT: The first integral can be rewritten using the above as:
\begin{align}\int_0^t\int_0^lu_{tt}u_tdxdt& =\frac12\int_0^l\int_0^t(u_t^2)_tdtdx\\ &=\frac12\int_0^l(u_t^2(t,x)-u_t^2(0,x))dx \\ &=\frac12\int_0^l(u_t^2(t,x)-g^2(x)))dx
\end{align}
The second integral can be dealt woth as follows: by partial integration over $x$ one has
\begin{align}-\int_0^t\int_0^lu_{xx}u_tdxdt&=-\int_0^tu_xu_t\bigg|_{x=0}^{x=l}dt+\int_0^t\int_0^lu_xu_{xt}dxdt
\end{align}
From the boundary conditions $u_x(t,0)=0=u_x(t,l)$ the first term is zero. The second can be rewritten using the second formula quoted above as
\begin{align}\int_0^t\int_0^lu_xu_{xt}dxdt&=\frac12\int_0^l\int_0^t(u_x^2)_tdtdx\\ & =\frac12\int_0^l(u_x^2(t,x)-u_x^2(0,x))dx\\
&=\frac12\int_0^l(u_x^2(t,x)-f_x^2(x))dx,
\end{align}
putting these together gives the result, up to a typo ($g_x$ and $f$ have to be replace with  $g$ and $f_x$ respectively)

Comment: so then i get that $\int_0^l \int_0^l (\frac{1}{2}(u_t^2)_t + u_xx u_t)dxdt = 0$ but Im not seeing how to use the fact that $u_x u_{xt} = 1/2 (u_x^2)_t$?

Comment: You still have to do partial integration on the second term with respect to $x$ (it is written in the answer, but maybe the bracket just after makes it hard to see)

Comment: would you mind working out a few more steps I'm still a bit confused

Comment: Not at all. Just give me a second to complete the answer

Comment: @Rufus full solution is up

Answer (score 0):

This is the equation that follow the waves on a string, I will use this to calculate the energy.

> Kinetic energy

Remember that the kinetic energy for a particle is simply $T = mv^2/2$, so for a small piece of the string the kinetic energy is

\begin{eqnarray}
dT &=& \frac{1}{2}dm \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{2}\rho ds \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{2}\rho \left[dx^2 + du^2 \right]^{1/2}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)^2 \\
&=& \frac{1}{2}\rho dx\left[1 +  \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2 \right]^{1/2}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)^2\\
&\approx& \frac{1}{2}\rho \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)^2 dx
\end{eqnarray}

where $\rho$ is the density and I have assumed that the slope of the string is small at any point $u_x^2 \ll 1$

The kinetic energy is then

$$
T(t) = \frac{1}{2}\rho\int_0^l dx\; \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)^2
$$

> Potential Energy

Image again a piece of the string, the length of a small piece is

$$
ds = [dx^2 + du^2]^{1/2} = \left[1 +  \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2 \right]^{1/2}dx \approx \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2 \right) dx
$$

This means that particular piece of string is going to stretch by an amount of $dx u_x^2/2$ when the wave is propagating. The work that the restoring force $F$ does is $Fds$ and therefore the potential energy stored in the string is

$$
U(t) = \frac{1}{2}F\int_0^l dx\; \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2
$$

Taking $\rho = 1$ and $F = 1$ (which is actually consistent with the fact that in your equation waves a propagating with speed $c=1 = (F/\rho)^{1/2}$), you get

$$
E(t) = T(t) + U(t) = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^l dx\; \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^l dx\; \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2
$$

And because energy is conserved

$$
E(t) = E(0) = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^ldx\;f_x^2(x) + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^ldx\;g^2(x)
$$